# Google Storage: how to check if an object exists?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

What is the best JSON API method to check if an object with the given name exists in a Google storage bucket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [storage.objects.get](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get) and check for a 404 response. Alternatively, if you want to create an object only if doesn't already exist, you can set the [ifGenerationMatch](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert#parameters) parameter to 0. If the object already exists, a precondition failure will be returned.

Comment: FYI: I tried to use `ifGenerationMatch` to avoid "Error 429: The total number of changes to the object ... exceeds the rate limit. Please reduce the rate of create, update, and delete requests., rateLimitExceeded", but it doesn't help.

Comment: for java sdk users: `Storage.BlobWriteOption.doesNotExist()`